# How to "undrain" slurm nodes in drain state

Tags: slurm

Using `sinfo` it shows 3 nodes are in `drain` state,

```
PARTITION AVAIL  TIMELIMIT  NODES  STATE NODELIST
all*         up   infinite      3  drain node[10,11,12]
```

Which command line should I use to *undrain* such nodes?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Found an approach, enter scontrol interpreter (in command line type `scontrol`) and then

```
scontrol: update NodeName=node10 State=DOWN Reason="undraining"
scontrol: update NodeName=node10 State=RESUME
```

Then

```
scontrol: show node node10
```

displays amongst other info

```
State=IDLE
```

**Update**: some of these nodes got DRAIN state back; noticed their root partition was full after e.g. `show node a10` which showed `Reason=SlurmdSpoolDir is full`, thus in Ubuntu `sudo apt-get clean` to remove `/var/cache/apt` contents and also gzipped some `/var/log` files.

Comment: You do not need to go through the DOWN state, you can directly issue the ``update ... state=resume`` command

Answer (score 31):

If no jobs are currently running on the node:

```
scontrol update nodename=node10 state=idle
```

If jobs are running on the node:

```
scontrol update nodename=node10 state=resume
```

Answer (score 16):

If you set it to down all jobs will be killed.

Set the node to RESUME instead.

Answer (score 4):

The other reason a node is in the DRAIN state is if the facts about the system do not match those declared in the /etc/slurm/slurm.conf file. For example, if the slurm.conf file declares that a node has 4 GPUs, but the slurm daemon only finds 3 of them, it will mark the node as "drain" because of the mismatch. Or if the node is declared in slurm.conf to have 128G of memory, and the slurm daemon only finds 96G, it will also set the state to "drain".

The reason code for mismatches is displayed by the 'scontrol show node ' command as the last line of output.

Comment: This turned out to be the case for me. I recently disabled SMT on my AMD processors and found all my nodes in the `drain` state because Slurm was expecting 2 threads per core (as that was what was in the node spec).

Answer (score 4):

While there is already an approved answer, I would like to mention that going through:

```
scontrol: update NodeName=nodename State=DOWN Reason="undraining"
scontrol: update NodeName=nodename State=RESUME
```

returns `slurm_update error: Invalid node state specified` for SLURM 21.08.03 on EndeavourOS 2021.08.27. The solution that worked for  me is:

```
scontrol: update NodeName=nodename State=UNDRAIN
```

Without need to set the node `DOWN`